# is there a character limitation in celery when sending messages to a rabbitmq broker ?

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, celery

I use celery and amqp broker and redis backend to queue tasks.in celery configuration , CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER has been set to json .
it works great and can send and get messages completely until content message characters ( value of result property in example ) are less than ~ 65000 , otherwise it is truncated .  is there a limitation on messages sent from celery ? if there is ,  how can i remove that ?

here is an example of what i got and saved to redis db . ( value of result property is truncated and the format is json . )

```js
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "traceback": null,
    "result": [
        0,
        ~500000 characters is truncated to ~65000 characters and the format is json
    ],
    "task_id": "567f6efa-16fd-439d-969e-d208e8e5876b",
    "children": []
}
```